# Permission error when accessing folder

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a web service to take all files found in a folder specified, eg C:/Incoming/20121018 and email them as attachments to an email address that I specify.

I can send a mail with one attachment successfully, but I thought I would pass several files via an array to be sent as attachments.  The only problem is that when I try to read the folder containing the files, I get a Permission error, even though I have rights to that folder. Any idea on where I'm going wrong?

See my code below:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Sending_Email(string strEmailAddrFrom, string[] strEmailAddrTo, int intTotalEmailTo, string [] strAttachement)
    {
        DateTime LeadDate;

        LeadDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        string Year = Convert.ToString(LeadDate.Year);
        string Month = Convert.ToString(LeadDate.Month);
        string Day = Convert.ToString(LeadDate.Day);
        string[] arr1 = new string[150];
        string Loc = "C:\\Incoming\\" + "" + Year + "" + Month + "" + Day + "";

        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Loc);
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Loc);
        FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles(".*.");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo fi in fileList)
        {
            arr1[count] = fi.Name;
        }

        EmailAlert NewMail = new EmailAlert();
        return NewMail.EmailSent(strEmailAddrFrom, strEmailAddrTo, intTotalEmailTo, arr1);
    }
```

Comment: You have the rights, but I suspect that the account under which the process runs doesn't.

Comment: stange to File.OpenText(Loc) and DirectoryInfo(Loc) with the same Loc. Which line throws ?

Comment: I do not think this is relevant to your error but you do not have `count++` in the foreach loop.

Comment: This line throws the error : StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Loc);

Comment: Loc is a directory or a file ?

Comment: @Ozgur - Yes, I forgot that. Added it in now.

Comment: you can't use File.OpenText with a directory name, imho that's why the line throws

Comment: Thanks.  Your'e right.  I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error lies here you are trying to open folder as stream which is not right way.

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Loc);
string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: you have not used string variable content in you later part of code. do you need to set this variable.